# how to configure external image server path in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We are working on to move our current e-commerce system to Hybris e-commerce.

In current system, external image server is used to feed for all product images used on product list/details pages. So I am looking for ways to configure these product images path (located for external server) in Hybris. I searched Hybris wiki but couldn't find much helpful info.

So i want to know where and how to configure external image server path so that all modules which uses product images can pick the correct path and display images accordingly. If some has done this sort of things before or has an idea, kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PCM cockpit, if you need to display product image that is on remote server you can follow these steps (i don't know if it's the best solution but at least it works) :

1. Add an attribute "pcmUrl" in the `Product` definition (items.xml)
2. Add to this attribute and attribute handler :  `<persistence type="dynamic" attributeHandler="pcmUrlAttribute" />`
3. Declare the bean : `<bean id="pcmUrlAttribute" class="mypackage.PcmUrlAttributeHandler"/>`
4. Define the `PcmUrlAttributeHandler` class that will contains the logic to retrieve the URL of the image on your remote server. The class has to `implements DynamicAttributeHandler<String, ProductModel>`
5. Now you have to customize the Product Cockpit. It's not so easy (my opinion) so I won't explain all steps here but basically you have to find out the view you want to customize and set:

   `<imageslot>
       <property qualifier="Product.pcmUrl" />
   </imageslot>`

Comment: Thanks @Alain. Understood. So basically there is no OOB facility available to keep your products images on remote server and show them with simple configurations, customization in PCM is necessary to achieve this. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @user098 Yes, OOB you can store your Media on the 3 following remote service storage : Amazon S3, Windows Azure Blob, and MongoDB GridFS. If you have you own remote server you have to implement the logic yourself. Also, if this answer has helped you, think about upvoting/accepting, ty.

Comment: @alain.janinm image slot has not been configured to work with editor where as it works well with grid-view

Answer (score 0):

Look at example media's URL for default apparel store they are configured with :

> media.apparel-de.http=http://apparel-de.local:9001
>
> media.apparel-de.https=https://apparel-de.local:9001

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. However i believe, above configuration will be useful for storefront product image display. where should i configure image server path for product cockpit so that when i search products in product cockpit, i should be able to products with proper images.